# Is it true that Stephen Hawking got the computer with his wheelchair by coincidence?

Tags: computers

In the recent movie about Stephen Hawking it is displayed that it is a coincidence that he got a computer with his wheelchair: Some friend was a computer engineer and installed the computer for him.

Is that more like a fact or just fiction?

I think today that it is normal with computers that help people in wheelchair and that Stephen Hawking would get that help today that in the movie was displayed a a coincidence that he had a friend who was a computer engineer.